# css3 column count overflow issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Using Column counts from BS4 Alpha. I have scale(1.02) for the hover state.  When you hover the card gets cut off and it looks like it wants to show the a new element below the 1st card.  Not sure how to prevent this behavior.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQFQ1.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcS5w.png

CSS

```
.card-columns{
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 20px;
-moz-column-gap: 20px;
column-gap: 20px;
}
.card-columns .card {
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.card {
position: relative;
background: #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.card.card-hover-colored:hover {
background: #EFFAFF;
}

.card.card-hover:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.02);
-ms-transform: scale(1.02);
-o-transform: scale(1.02);
transform: scale(1.02);
box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
cursor: pointer;
}
```

CODE

```
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card card-hover" >
      <div class="card-block">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-hc-4x zmdi-check"></i>
        <h4>Twitter Account</h4>
        <p>Connect your Twitter account before to start sharing content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-hover">
      <div class="card-block">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-hc-4x zmdi-check"></i>
        <h4>Share on Twitter</h4>
        <p>Successfully share content on Twitter.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Make a working fiddle.  Images aren't very helpful.

Comment: create a jsfiddle for it and we can help easier

Comment: @jmargolisvt here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agbL8b5h/)

Comment: Does this fix it? https://jsfiddle.net/agbL8b5h/1/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle @zgood !  Adam - it does fix it, but I am using cards all over my site and the 5px top margin will mess up the layout on a bunch of pages.  Worst case i can work with that, but was hoping there was a better way.